# Python - how can I use generators more succinctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

(Python 3)

I am using a Python generator to read messages from a queue.

After the consumer reads a queue message, it needs to be able to tell the generator to delete the queue message if it was successfully processed.

In order to .send() to a Python generator, it seems I must first .send(None) to the generator. This is making my code fatter than I think it should be.

Can anyone suggest a way for qconsumer.py to drive the generator with fewer lines of code? I have identified which lines below I am hoping to eliminate.

In short, how can I make the code below more compact, any suggestions for how I can delete lines?

Code below is qconsumer.py:

```
from qserver import Qserver

myqserver = Qserver()

myproducer = myqserver.producer() # trying to eliminate this line
# first send to a generator must be None
myproducer.send(None) # trying to eliminate this line
for msg in myproducer:
    # do something with message
    print(msg)
    if messageprocessok:
        myproducer.send('delete')
```

Code below is qserver.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message

QNAME = 'qinbound'
SQSREGION = 'us-west-1'

class Qserver():
    """A simple Q server."""

    def __init__(self, qname=None, sqsregion=None):
        self.qname = qname or QNAME
        self.sqsregion = sqsregion or SQSREGION
        self.sqsconn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(self.sqsregion)
        self.q_in = self.sqsconn.get_queue(self.qname)

    def producer(self):
        while True:
            qmessage = self.q_in.read(wait_time_seconds=20)
            if qmessage is None:
                continue
            action = (yield qmessage.get_body())
            if action == 'delete':
                # if processing completed ok, clear message from this queue
                self.q_in.delete_message(qmessage)
```

Comment: Are you sure you need it? `None` is the only thing that you can send to a non-started generator, but you certainly aren't required to. A simple test of your `qconsumer.py` code (with a simpler dummy generator) works fine without calling `myproducer.send(None)`. However, `generator.send()` _returns_ the next value of the generator; you're mixing iterating the generator in your `for` loop and pulling next values explicitly using `myproducer.send` — you should use only one or the other.

Comment: @lanzz hmmm.... sounds like my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having understood what you're trying to do, I think I would avoid mixing `send` with iteration. Having the `myqserver` class be an iterator itself seems to make more sense to me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import boto
from boto.sqs.connection import SQSConnection
from boto.sqs.message import Message

QNAME = 'qinbound'
SQSREGION = 'us-west-1'

class Qserver():
    """A simple Q server."""
    _current_message = None

    def __init__(self, qname=None, sqsregion=None):
        self.qname = qname or QNAME
        self.sqsregion = sqsregion or SQSREGION
        self.sqsconn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(self.sqsregion)
        self.q_in = self.sqsconn.get_queue(self.qname)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            qmessage = self.q_in.read(wait_time_seconds=20)
            if qmessage is not None:
                self._current_message = qmessage
                return qmessage

    next = __next__

    def delete_current(self):
        if self._current_message is not None:
            self.q_in.delete_message(self._current_message)
```

And usage will be something like:

```
from qserver import Qserver

myqserver = Qserver()
for msg in myqserver:
    # do something with message
    print(msg)
    if messageprocessok:
        myqserver.delete_current()
```

Comment: looks interesting. Can you explain your thinking behind recommending avoiding mixing send with iteration?  What's the problem with doing that?

Comment: Mainly because it keeps things simpler. Generators that either just consume data (through `send`) or just produce data (by yielding) are much easier to understand and debug. If you use both, you need to be careful, since as someone mentioned above, `send` causes the generator to resume execution until the next `yield` is encounter. If the next `yield` is a statement and not an expression, the result will be returned with the call to `send`. If you are not careful with that, you lose the returned value.

Comment: if I wanted to be able to also write messages to the queue would it make sense just to add a "writemessage" method to your suggested implementation of Qserver?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question in my previous (now deleted) comment. Yes, a method like `write_message` or `add_message` which would add a message to the queue would be the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your current consumer is throwing away messages because each `send` call returns one. You should do this instead:

```
myqserver = Qserver()
myproducer = myqserver.producer() 
messageprocessok = False
while True:
    msg = myproducer.send('delete' if messageprocessok else None)
    # do something with message
    print(msg)
```

or alternatively:

```
myqserver = Qserver()
myproducer = myqserver.producer() 
msg = next(myproducer)
while True:
    # do something with message
    print(msg)
    msg = myproducer.send('delete' if messageprocessok else None)
```

The fact that you need separate calls to `Qserver()` and  `myqserver.producer()` is simply because you made `prouducer` a method of a class. Alternatively you could use a stand-alone function, or make a wrapper function that simply returns  `Qserver().producer()`. Here's the stand-alone version:

```
def producer(qname=None, sqsregion=None):
    qname = qname or QNAME
    sqsregion = sqsregion or SQSREGION
    sqsconn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(sqsregion)
    q_in = sqsconn.get_queue(qname)
    while True:
        qmessage = q_in.read(wait_time_seconds=20)
        if qmessage is None:
            continue
        action = (yield qmessage.get_body())
        if action == 'delete':
            # if processing completed ok, clear message from this queue
            q_in.delete_message(qmessage)
```

Comment: Hi @Janne. We won't know if messageprocessok until the message has been processed.  Does that fit with your solution?

Comment: @DukeDougal The first call needs to be `myproducer.send(None)` or alternatively `next(myproducer)`. I'm initializing `messageprocessok = False` to accomplish that. On the first call the generator runs from the beginning up to the point when it yields the first message.

Comment: Valuable information. I'm marking the other one as the solution because that's what I'm going to use but your approachs also seems good. StackOverflow says there can be only one solution......